# How do I create objects in a specific container in my Qt Creator MainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

Hopefully this question is an easy one. I need to generate a few buttons at run-time in a specific area of my GUI. The objects I want to create are checkboxes. Here is the part of the code that creates these checkboxes:

```
void MainWindow::on_generateBoxes_clicked()
{
    int x_dim = ui->xDim->value();
    int y_dim = ui->yDim->value();
    int z_dim = ui->zDim->value();
    QVector<QCheckBox*> checkBoxVector;
    for(int i = 0; i < x_dim; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < y_dim; ++j){
            checkBoxVector.append(new QCheckBox( ui->dim1 ));
            checkBoxVector.last()->setGeometry(i * 20, j * 20, 20, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how do I take this idea, but create these checkboxes in the specific area I want? The area is called dim1, and it is a widget of a QTabWidget.

EDIT: Updated the code

Comment: anybody else have any suggestions?

Comment: at least one thing is obviously wrong here: you create your checkboxes in a QVector that's local to on_generateBoxes_clicked()
. The vector gets destroyed after the method returns. (Not sure this destroys the CheckBoxes, since the Vector only holds pointers)

Comment: Are you sure this dim1 shows up? Maybe try a color that must be visible.And for completeness I would make sure the values in x_dim and y_dim are not zero. output them to qDebug or something

Comment: Sorry I was away all week. I got it working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troubadour is basically right, that you need to set the right widget as parent. Though QScrollArea has by default no widget, you need to create it like this:

```
checkBoxArea = new QScrollArea(this); // this is the MainWindow or other parent
background = new QWidget;
checkBoxArea->setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 200);
checkBoxArea->setWidgetResizable(true); 
checkBoxArea->setWidget(background);
background->show();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j){
        checkBoxVector.append(new QCheckBox(background));
        checkBoxVector.last()->setGeometry(i * 20, j * 20, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

important is that you use `checkBoxArea->setWidgetResizable(true)` otherwise you would have to set the size manually each time you resize.

If a widget doesn't show up where you expect it to, this most of the time has one of those reasons:

- wrong parent
- invisible: use show()
- zero size: use setGeoemetry

Comment: This one didn't work either. It doesn't give an error, it just doesn't create checkboxes anywhere. (sorry for the delayed response)

Comment: that's strange. i put this code in an empty project and the boxes show as expected. i corrected `background.show()` to `background->show()` but that doesnt matter, the show command is not necessary. can you post the actual code you use? otherwise: a 'trick' I sometimes use to find out which widgets show and which fail is to set backgroundcolors to something obvious like red.

Comment: I updated my question with the new code, where dim1 is a QWidget.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to parent the checkboxes to the `MainWindow` as then their positions will be relative to that widget. Instead you want to parent them to the widget of the `QCsrollArea` i.e.

```
checkBoxVector.append(new QCheckBox(checkBoxArea->widget()));
```

I assume you have set a widget on the `QScrollArea`? If not then just use a plain `QWidget` i.e.

```
checkBoxArea->setWidget( new QWidget() );
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work. The checkboxes aren't generated anywhere.